# Null-coalescing operator with ref keyword

Tags: c#, operators, ref, null-coalescing-operator

**EDIT**

Here is a better explaination to my problem. Especially to answer to question "Why I want to use references, and why not just use `double?`".

So I actually have the following variables:

```
double? Left_A, Left_B;
double? Right_A, Right_B;
double? Result_Left, Result_Right;
```

The user either sets value of the left variables, or the right ones. It is handled in my ViewModel. I am calculating the values of results, based on 
 some formulas like `result = a * b` etc.

The formulas are the same for left or right variables.

So I just wanted to create a "pointer" like reference variables, 'a' and 'b', whose value would be the value of `Left_A` or `Left_B` so that I don't have to do the following:

```
if(Left_A != null) {
    Result_Left = Left_A * Left_B;
} else {
    Result_Right = Right_A * Right_B;
}
//There are more such formulas for many use-cases..
```

I wanted something like this..

```
ref double? result, a, b;
a = ref Left_A ?? ref Right_A;  //This gives error.
b = ref (Left_B ?? Right_B);  //This gives error.
result = Result_Left ?? Result_Right;

result = a * b;
```

I hope I am not doing something wrong in this..

---

I am trying to use the [Null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) with the [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

My assignment statement is as follows:

Note: According to my business logic which is omitted here, it is guaranteed that both a & b won't be null. Either of them will have a value.

```
double? x = a ?? b;   // a and b are also of type "double?".
```

However I want `x` to be a reference type variable. Is this possible?

I tried the following, but all of them give compilation errors. Especially the last one:

- `ref double? x = ref (a ?? b);`
- `ref double? x = ref a ?? ref b;`
- `ref double? x = (ref a) ?? (ref b);`
- `ref double? param1 = ref ( please work!!!  -.-' );`

Any ideas?

Comment: is still not clear what you want. Why reference? Why two variables? How you want them to be in one at the same time? Seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: *I want x to be a reference type variable* - What do you mean by that? what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: What is wrong with `double? x = a ?? b;`?

Comment: Maybe you want to use pointers, then? They are pretty much references.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Pl. check the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a method:

```
ref double? GetValue(ref double? a, ref double? b) {
    if (a == null) return ref b; else return ref a;
}
```

then,

```
ref double? x = ref GetValue(ref a, ref b);
```

I don't think it can be done using the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: While that's a valid syntax in C#7, What would be the point here? why not just `double? x = a ?? b;` ?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten the point is to change the original variable, not sure why tho. VijayChavda, can you tell us what is it you reallly want please?

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about a function... don't see the point.

Comment: @Dennis_E Although I didn't expect I'd require a function, but I'll try this way anyways. Please check the edit in case you needed some better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the `ref` keyword here.
The following will work:

```
double a = (double) (Left_A ?? Right_A);
double b = (double) (Left_B ?? Right_B);
double result = a * b;
```

Or with one liner:

```
result = (double) (leftA ?? rightA) * (double) (leftB ?? rightB);
```

Comment: I actually wanted changes to be reflected in the original variables (L/R)... and also i was curious how to make ?? and ref work together :)  turns out, we can't!

Comment: Then why don't you wrap these variables and the logic in a class and use it to provide your result every time...?

Comment: Good suggestion. but the dilemma of checking everytime whether i have to assign the result to L/R would still remain.

Comment: Maybe i can use `out` params in those methods, according to your idea..

Answer (score 0):

> //It is guaranteed that either a/b is not null.

It's not guaranteed. It simply checks if `a` is null, and then if it is, it assigns `b` to `x`.

If both your variables are `double?` and you don't need a result yo be nullable, then you can use `.GetValueOrDefault()` for that:

```
double x = (a ?? b).GetValueOrDefault();
double x = (a ?? b).GetValueOrDefault(-0.5); // Or this.
```

Comment: No. I just meant that both a and b won't be null, according to my business logic. I am not saying the next statement is going to ensure that..

Comment: Please check the Edit, I have made myself clear now :)

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with the question. You're not even addressing the `ref` problem.

Comment: @adjan of course, because the question isn't very clear.